# My isset condition never becomes true. Why is that?

Tags: php, isset

```
<form name="login" action=""<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <label for="usermail">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="username" required>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>

            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <?php
        $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "agentie");
        if (isset($_POST["nume"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
            if (($_POST["nume"] == "admin") && ($_POST["password"] == "admin123")) {
                echo "ati intrat in panoul de control";
            }

            $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT user, password FROM user u WHERE u.user='$_POST[nume]'") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connection));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
                if (($row["user"] == $_POST["nume"]) && ($row["password"] == $_POST["password"]))
                    echo "Bine ati venit" . $row["user"];
            }
        }
        ?>
```

I do not know why my 2 issets never becomes true. If i remove the if condition, and I 
`simply print $_POST["nume"]` and  `$_POST["password"]`, they appear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are duplicate double quotes around your action - maybe they are causing the trouble.

Comment: Should be `action=""` - using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` screws up any kind of query string or "pretty URLs" you may decide to use.

Comment: why do you need isset there? just start with the  `if ($_POST[] == "");` condition, if it isnt set then it will return a null.. should work anyway.

Comment: @bakriawad `if ($_POST[] == "");` is not valid code...

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko I've tried whith simple quotes too.

Comment: @Tim the point is the condition, more like peusedo there.. in his case it would be `if (($_POST["nume"] == "admin") && ($_POST["password"] == "admin123"))`, the isset condition can be skipped

Comment: @user3806279 I mean, it should be `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` instead of `action=""<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>""`

Comment: @bakriawad it would have been a better comment to put that rather than the first comment which may confuse the OP

Answer (score 0):

your isset works but the nested if statement is not matched try echoing it in first if statement.

```
if (isset($_POST["nume"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
      echo $_POST["nume"]; 
      echo $_POST["password"];
            if (($_POST["nume"] == "admin") && ($_POST["password"] == "admin123")) {
                echo "ati intrat in panoul de control";
            }
```

Comment: @user3806279 i didnt get you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<label for="usermail">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="username" required>

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>

<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST["nume"], $_POST["password"])) {
    echo "It works";
    if (($_POST["nume"] == "admin") && ($_POST["password"] == "admin123")) {
        echo "ati intrat in panoul de control";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST`variable is not evaluated.
Change this:
`$query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT user, password FROM user u WHERE u.user='$_POST[nume]'") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connection));`

into

`$query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT user, password FROM user u WHERE u.user='{$_POST[nume]}'") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connection));`